# Spring Data Rest - How to prevent PUT/PATCH updates to child entities of aggregate root

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm building a Spring Data REST / Spring HATEOAS based application and I'm attempting to following the principles of DDD outlined here (and elsewhere):

[BRIDGING THE WORLDS OF DDD & REST - Oliver Gierke](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/conference/2016/07/10/SpringIO16-DDD-Rest.html)

In particular the concept of aggregates and complex state changes via dedicated resources.

> Also avoid using HTTP PATCH or PUT for (complex) state transitions of your business domain because you are missing out on a lot of information regarding the real business domain event that triggered this update. For example, changing a customer’s mailing address is a POST to a new "ChangeOfAddress" resource, not a PATCH or PUT of a “Customer” resource with a different mailing address field value.

What I'm struggling with is a means of enforcing this while allowing cosmetic changes to the aggregate root.

Using this simplified example:

```
@Entity
public class Customer
{
   private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) Long id;

   private String name;

   private String comment;

   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

   ... getters and setters

    public void addAddress(Address address)
    {
        addresses.add(address);
        ... custom code to raise events etc
    }
}

public interface Customer extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>
{
}
```

What is the best/correct way to allow a cosmetic change (e.g. update comment) but but prevent changes that directly update the child collection?

The only thing I can think of doing if having the setter throw an exception if there is an attempt to modify the child collection.

Comment: Congratulations, you just hit one of the meter-deep potholes in SDR.

Comment: You can prevent the data reading from request at the mapping moment. If you are using Jackson - mark your child collections with `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)`. So this field will be allowed only to be served, but not updated.

Comment: @BogdanOros Thanks this works great, if you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think this is necessarily a shortcoming of SDR, I'd have still been stuck with the same problem if I'll used Spring mvc/hateoas and hand written the controller. The question stems more from attempting to implement the aggregate pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
public class Customer
{
   private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) Long id;

   private String name;

   private String comment;

   @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Bogdan Oros. It'd be nice if at least one of the spring data rest examples covered this. It does seem to be a major consideration in the application of the aggregate pattern.